# Check radio button state/value

Tags: jquery

I' ve this form

```
<input type="radio" name="KDX_Type" value="new"> New
<input type="radio" name="KDX_Type" value="existing"> Existing
```

I've this JS line:

```
if($('input[name="KDX_Type"]:checked').val()=='existing') { alert('Fire'); }
```

Problem: my alert do not fire up.

Any chance you could know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: When is this line ran?

Comment: the radio button is not checked so its value is undefined. put checked attribute to 2nd checkbox and if statement will work

Comment: @tymeJV: after the HTML.

Comment: @AamirAfridi: If the user change it it will not work. By default, I do not want any radio checked.

Comment: Neither box is checked. Is this code being executed from a click or change event handler?

Comment: Show us the rest of your code .. .. like when you check the radio button and when you fire the if statement code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
$('input[name="KDX_Type"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'existing') {
        alert('Fire');
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uMgsb/)**